# Display all the running processes of the linux system under the super user why not is `ps -a`?

Tags: linux

Display all the running processes of the linux system under the super user.

```
ps -aux
```

why not

```
ps a
```

Comment: It actually used to be just `a` with no leading `-`. There have been changes over the years and someone wrote about it extensively here: https://askubuntu.com/a/485092

Comment: According to the manual page, `ps -a` lists *all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal*. Why does it exclude session leaders and processes not associated with a terminal? Because the authors of `ps` decided it so. By the way, `ps -aux` doesn't list all processes,  but only those of user *x*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is to be found in the
[ps man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html):

```
 a      Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction, which is
              imposed upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style
              (without "-") options are used or when the ps personality
              setting is BSD-like.  The set of processes selected in
              this manner is in addition to the set of processes
              selected by other means.  An alternate description is that
              this option causes ps to list all processes with a
              terminal (tty), or to list all processes when used
              together with the x option.

 -a     Select all processes except both session leaders (see
        getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a terminal.
```

The `ps` command supports two styles, for historical reasons of
compatibility, BSD or Linux.

BSD stands for "Berkeley Software Distribution", a set of modifications to Bell Unix created at the University of California, Berkeley,
a long long time ago. It eventually grew into a complete operating system
and there are now even multiple different BSDs.

The dash before the `ps` option usually denotes the choice of the BSD
variant (if one exists).

For some reason, under BSD, `ps` did not list
session leaders and processes not associated with a terminal.
I really can't say why.

You should use `ps a`, the non-BSD variant, to see all processes.
Other useful display format options are `f` (full) and `l` (long).